# transform.Translate not working properly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am developing a game in which I want infinity road, So I created 40 instances of the road which I want to repeat again and again.

I am writing the following code to change the position of road that is not visible in the camera now and can be repeated

```
roadPaths[currentRoad].transform.Translate(Vector3(0,0,startPositionValue));
```

But I am getting the following log

[image: Log]

In the above log you can see when the startPositionValue is 42, currentRoad position becomes 43. Same issue is with other values as well.

A help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: Hi Lex, I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate is a relative move of the GameObject in three-dimensional space. It literally translates it from the current position by a relative value to a new position that is an offset from the original.

Explicitly setting the Position vector of the GameObject's Transform will set it to an absolute position within the world.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I am able to solve the issue.

The following code work

```
roadPaths[currentRoad].transform.position=Vector3(0,0,startPositionValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is very simple:

```
transform.Translate(X, Y, Z);
```

for exemple:

```
transform.Translate(5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
//GameObject moves smooth at the positive direction of the X position
```